# compile razor views in .net core

Tags: razor, compilation, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-cli

Is there a way I can compile all my razor views (to verify) any time I need? I found this doc which shows how it compiles on publish https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x.

I am looking for an option within visual studio or even better via CLI that compiles and validates all views. I did find this official razor CLI tool in preview, but no documentation: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools/1.1.0-preview4-final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can publish any time you need. The name ‘publish’ does not mean ‘push my site to the coliseum of public opinion’ :-)

All that it does stays local, and `dotnet publish` will by default create a directory under your project `bin` folder with, as you say, compiled views and other artefacts.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2122#issuecomment-369393860), with .NET core 2.1 you can compile razor views at build time without needing to publish, by adding these two lines to the `<PropertyGroup>` section of your project file:

```
<RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
<ResolvedRazorCompileToolset>RazorSdk</ResolvedRazorCompileToolset>
```

This will cause them to compile to a [project].Views.dll, and you'll no longer need to distribute the cshtml files.

Comment: yep. i have noticed this. i guess this is there by default

Comment: just noticed something about this feature today. .net core seems to create autogenerated classes to achieve this compile time checks. Knowing this might be useful for certain kinds of debugging